# Linux application or distribution with window snapping (like Windows 7)

Tags: linux, windows-7

In Windows 7, if I pull a window to the side of the screen, then it snaps there and takes half of the screen space.

Is there a Linux distribution that comes with this feature?  Or is there an application that I can install to do this?

I found references to Compiz Aero Snap in a bunch of places, but it looked more complicated than what I was hoping for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gnome 3.4 on Fedora 17 even did this. Try any modern distro.

Comment: unity (ubuntu) does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has that feature included with its Unity desktop environment. Currently they are in version 14.04 LTS. You can grab a copy [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

It has all snap gestures Windows 7 and 8.1 desktop mode use.

For example, snap to top to maximize window:
[image: Snap to the top to maximize the app]